# Run Maven webapp on server from Eclipse with properties injection from profile

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I use Eclipse & Maven to develop a Spring + Hibernate webapp, and in my `pom.xml` I have several profiles with different properties that I inject to a `.properties` file. This file is used in `applicationContext.xml` to configure Spring, and when I want to launch the application, I'm obliged to deploy it on a running tomcat outside Eclipse. Here is some parts of my code :

**pom.xml :**

```
...
<profile>
    <id>development</id>
    <properties>
        <db.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClassName>
        <db.name>mydbname</db.name>
        <db.params>?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</db.params>

        <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>update</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
        <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>

        <log4j.spring.level>WARN</log4j.spring.level>
        <log4j.hibernate.level>WARN</log4j.hibernate.level>
    </properties>
</profile>
...
```

**application.properties :**

```
...
# JDBC Information
# Some properties are in my .m2/settings.xml
jdbc.driver.classname=${db.driverClassName}
jdbc.url=${db.url}/${db.name}${db.params}
jdbc.user=${db.username}
jdbc.pass=${db.password}
...
```

**applicationContext.xml :**

```
...
<!-- JDBC Data Source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver.classname}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
</bean>
...
```

Using the Tomcat7 Maven plugin, deployment via `mvn tomcat7:deploy` works fine, but when I choose *"Right-click > Run as > Run on server"*, I get a lot of exceptions related to the placeholders :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.driverClassName' in string value "${db.driverClassName}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:161)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:206)
    ... 17 more
```

How can I run my project in the Eclipse embedded Tomcat and get the logs in the console instead of in `logs/catalina.out` ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: why dont you just have the properties in the properties file instead of injecting them?

Comment: Because I have multiple profiles, and the values depend on the profile used to build :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !

As I'm using the Maven Eclipse plugin, I have a "Maven" entry under the project properties *(Project > Properties > Maven)*. I just had to activate the "development" profile and it worked !

[image: Project Properties]