# Eclipse deploying unfiltered .WAR-Archive on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

i have the following problem: I want to use maven profiles and the maven-war-plugin for filtering my webapplication, so that it's just one click to deploy it either on the live- or on the development server.

When i build the .WAR-archive via Eclipse (Maven-Plugin) and then manually deploy it on the tomcat-server via the tomcat-manager-interface, my application works as expected. (all variables are replaced correctly inside the generated .WAR-archive)

But when i want to run the application using **Eclipse's "Run on Server"**, an exception occurs:

> [..] nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ${security.casEntryPoint.logoutSuccessUrl} isn't a valid redirect URL

This is the configuration of the maven profiles in my pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/dfnaaiAgreement-prod.properties</filter>
        </filters>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>devLocal</id>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/dfnaaiAgreement-devLocal.properties</filter>
        </filters>
    </build>
</profile>
```

This is an example entry for the *.properties file:

```
security.casEntryPoint.logoutSuccessUrl = https://example_entry/please_logmeout
```

This is one entry in the settings.xml that should be replaced by the value in the *.properties file:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="${security.casEntryPoint.logoutSuccessUrl}" />
```

and this is the configuration for the maven plugin (in the pom.xml), that is used for filtering the configuration files:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
    <warName>dfnaaiAgreement</warName>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
</configuration>
```

This is my maven build configuration:

[Maven-Build configuration (Sorry, not enough reputation to post images directly)](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/eclipsem7hdr521c9.png)

It seems like eclipse's "run on server" deploys the unfiltered application on the tomcat-server.
What am i doing wrong?

**Update:**
I followed this Link [Run Maven webapp on server from Eclipse with properties injection from profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220630/run-maven-webapp-on-server-from-eclipse-with-properties-injection-from-profile?rq=1), but i'am still receiving the same Exception.

Here's the adjustment of my project's configuration: [Active Maven Profiles](http://postimg.org/image/lmau05vy3)

**Update:** Eclipse (Luna) deploys the webapplication to workspace/.metadata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/applicationName. The settings.xml that's deployed there still contains the unfiltered variables, whereas the generated .WAR-Archive (that is located at workspace/applicationName/target)  has the correctly filtered settings.xml. How is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220630/run-maven-webapp-on-server-from-eclipse-with-properties-injection-from-profile?rq=1

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't find this topic. Thanks that solves my problem!

Comment: Unfortunately i was wrong. It is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not an optimal solution i found a workaround to fix my problem. Therefor i adjusted the project's deployment assembly settings in the way that the WEB-INF-Folder of the target-Folder will be taken for deployment.

You can do this by rightclicking your project and choose "Properties". Here's a screenshot of how i adjusted the settings:

[Web_Deployment_Assembly.PNG](http://postimg.org/image/a82yt1hf5/)

Comment: The link is dead.